# Maven Purge Repository

Tags: maven-3, purge

I am having issues using Maven's: `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` command. 
I have several versions of a project and would like to remove certain versions.

I am running the command:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DactTransitively=false -DreResolve=false -DresolutionFuzziness=version
```

The command runs with success but nothing is purged(deleted) from my local .m2 repository.

I have closely watched the windows explorer while the command runs, and I see items being deleted, repopulated, and deleted again, but in the end nothing has changed and the same files I wanted gone remain.

Can anyone explain what I am missing, or not fully understanding of how to use the tool?

thanks,

Cameron

Comment: You haven't given the -Dincludes=groupId:artifactId which should be deleted. And why not just simply deleting the whole locale repository and that's it. Are you using a repository manager?

Comment: OK I will add the -Dincludes=groupID:artifactID to my command. I am not deleting the whole repository, because there are certain versions that we'd like to keep on hand. But most are tags that will never be used again so I am trying to find the best way to remove items I find not needed anymore.

Comment: Sounds like you are not using a repository manager which i can recomment which will solve this problem.

Comment: No I'm not using a repository manager. So just to be clear the purge-local-repo command is to remove files totally from the repository no different than you blowing those files or directories away manually through windows explorer, just it is built into maven through that command and various arguments?